# Porque o meu foreach está duplicando os meu registros do Banco de Dados?

Tags: php, banco-de-dados, mysqli

```
function DBRead($table, $params = null, $fields = '*'){
    $table  = DB_PREFIX.'_'.$table;
    $params = ($params) ? " {$params}" : null;

    $query  = "SELECT {$fields} FROM {$table}{$params}";
    $result = DBExecute($query);

    if(!mysqli_num_rows($result))
        return false;
    else{
        while ($res = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
            $data[] = $res;
        }
        return $data;
    }
}

$publicacao = DBRead('publicacao');
    foreach ($publicacao as $pl):
    endforeach;

    <?php foreach ($publicacao as $pl): ?>
        <li>
            <h4><a href="#"><?php echo $pl['title']?></a></h4>

            <h5><?php echo $pl['text']?><a href="%">Continue lendo &raquo;</a></h5>
        </li>
    <?php endforeach; ?>

    <?php foreach ($publicacao as $pl): ?>
        <li>
            <h4><a href="#"><?php echo $pl['title']?></a></h4>

            <h5><?php echo $pl['text']?><a href="%">Continue lendo &raquo;</a></h5>
        </li>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
```

Eu coloquei um **print_r($publicacao)** entre a linha **$publicacao = DBRead('publicacao');** e **foreach ($publicacao as $pl):** Resultado está abaixo:

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [id] => 33 [title] => First Title [text] => First Text ) [1] => Array ( [id] => 34 [title] => Second Title [text] => Second Text ) )
```

Já o **print_r($publicacao)** que coloquei entre o **foreach ($publicacao as $pl):** e **endforeach;** o resultado é esse:

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [id] => 33 [title] => First Title [text] => First Text ) [1] => Array ( [id] => 34 [title] => Second Title [text] => Second Text ) ) Array ( [0] => Array ( [id] => 33 [title] => First Title [text] => First Text ) [1] => Array ( [id] => 34 [title] => Second Title [text] => Second Text ) )
```

No meu Banco de Dados eu só tenho 2 registros. Porque está duplicado?

Comment: Bem vinda!, Porque ele vai printar quantas vezes o foreach executar... É a mesma coisa que um for se você fizer for($i=0; $i <2; $i++){ print_r($publicacao); } esse for vai ser executado duas vezes, e obviamente o print_r será printado 2x porém vai depender de quantos registros sua $publicação tem

Comment: @AndersonHenrique Olá, eu tenho dois registros. Como eu resolvo isso, poderia me ajudar?

Comment: Dê uma olhada na resposta abaixo @Susi

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Faça assim, o foreach vai executar quantas vezes for necessário até chegar ao fim do array retornado (quantidade dos seus registros) então esses 3 foreach não são necessários. Só remova os outros 2

```
function DBRead($table, $params = null, $fields = '*'){
    $table  = DB_PREFIX.'_'.$table;
    $params = ($params) ? " {$params}" : null;

    $query  = "SELECT {$fields} FROM {$table}{$params}";
    $result = DBExecute($query);

    if(!mysqli_num_rows($result))
        return false;
    else{
        while ($res = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
            $data[] = $res;
        }
        return $data;
    }
}

$publicacao = DBRead('publicacao');

    <?php foreach ($publicacao as $pl): ?>
        <li>
            <h4><a href="#"><?php echo $pl['title']?></a></h4>

            <h5><?php echo $pl['text']?><a href="%">Continue lendo &raquo;</a></h5>
        </li>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
```

Comment: Resolveu. Muito obrigada <3

Comment: Que isso, que bom que ajudou